# Convert 24-bit color to specific 8-bit color pallette

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, colors

i am trying to use a standard color picker for a windows phone app (c#), which delivers a 24bit color to set the color of some light-bulbs which have an 8bit color palette as described below. When i first thought about it i didnt think it wouldn be such a big deal, after spending a few hours with no result at all, i now think it might be, though. Hope anyone here has a brilliant idea. Color palette:

```
0x00 Violet
0x10 Royal_Blue
0x20 Baby_Blue
0x30 Aqua
0x40 Mint
0x50 Seafoam_Green
0x60 Green
0x70 Lime_Green
0x80 Yellow
0x90 Yellow_Orange
0xA0 Orange
0xB0 Red
0xC0 Pink
0xD0 Fusia
0xE0 Lilac
0xF0 Lavendar
```

(colors in between should be used)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Converting to HSB [might help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/105206d5-f7f7-4848-a32e-2b5cc10dc56f/how-to-find-the-nearest-matching-color-?forum=winforms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Coding4Fun library](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) or even do [the custom picker](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Custom_Color_Picker_for_Windows_Phone) - it's not hard at all.

Comment: I am using the codepicker from the coding4fun library but still the problem is the same, the picker delivers a color with RGB values, but i need an int value that maps to the color palette in my original post. I don't have problems using the color picker, but converting the value to something that i can use.

Comment: Using picker with limited colors is better than converting.

Comment: I agree with that, I didn't find a way to limit the color palette of the coding4fun picker, but i might give the custom picker a shot, thanks for the link. So far i am using a simple slider, after seeing the color picker i might as well just create some kind of color-key for the slider.

Comment: You can find the custom picker sample in the `ColorHexagonPicker.cs` in Coding4Fun library.